# hook_file_download is invoked when the file is deleted

Tags: hooks

I have a implementation of hook_file_download because I check if this is a private/specific file and do a redirection for specific link:

```
function my_file_download($uri) {

 //some code here
 // if(substr($uri,0,26) =='private://specificcontent/'){
    header("location:http://mysite.com/myURL");
```

}

But, when I remove a file such as image below, this function too is called, generating a error, because the code try redirect for "http://mysite.com/myURL". I believe that when the file is deleted, not is correct receive a call in hook_file_download. But, case if it is not evitable, what I need do for verify that is a delete command and ignore redirection command?

[image]

Comment: This hook is not supposed to do a redirect and this is causing the problem. It should return file headers, NULL, or -1, see: [hook_file_download/7.x](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7.x). Why do you need that redirect here? Private files can be served from the directory outside the web root on the original "system/private/XXX" path.

Comment: I need collect user data (with form) before download an private/specific file.

Comment: Then you can check in your code, if `current_path()` is `system/ajax` (then disable redirect, as it will be the file deletion) or if the `current_path()` is `system/private/XXX` (then you can leave the redirect here, as it will be direct request for the file).

Comment: Is exactly what I did. Thanks.